# How to set icons on the right side of an Appbar using material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make an Appbar component. I have a menu icon and company name on the left side.Now I want to display profile icon,notification icon and welcome string on the far right of the Appbar component.

I have used div tag with margin-left:auto property but i want it to be done using grid component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Appbar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import { Toolbar, IconButton, Typography, Avatar, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import Menu from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import Notify from "@material-ui/icons/Notifications";
export class Appbar_component extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            //static position keeps the appbar at the top 
            <Grid container>

                <Appbar position='static'
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(74, 144, 226, 1)"
                    }}
                >
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Grid item>
                            {/* all the conreols that are at the left side */}
                            <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit">
                                <Menu />
                            </IconButton>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>

                            <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" style={{ marginLeft: '40px' }}>
                                <b>
                                    Cetra Business Travel
                        </b>
                            </Typography>
                        </Grid>
                        {/* controls that are at the right side */}
                        <div
                            style={{
                                marginLeft: "auto",
                            }}
                        >
                            <Grid item>
                                <Typography variant='title'>Welcome User!</Typography>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>

                                <IconButton color="inherit" >
                                    <Notify />
                                </IconButton>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>

                                <IconButton>
                                    <Avatar src='./Images/profile_image.png' si />
                                </IconButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </div>
                    </Toolbar>
                </Appbar>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}

export default Appbar;
```

When i use the grid components it changes the layout so that only the icons and string at the right side of the Appbar are shown in different row and i want it to be on the same row(side by side)

Comment: What is the motivation for using the Grid component for this? Why are you avoiding the div solution?

Comment: I want to use grid component's xs and lg attributes to provide a responsive view.Is there any other way to provide that? or will it provide me a responsive view?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of of using the div with with margin-left: auto, you can just add another Grid item between the Grid item with the label and the Grid item with the user info.

```
<Grid item xs/>
```

the xs tells the Grid item to use all the remaining Grid space within the Grid container

Have a look at [this code sandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-j5c74?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Grid container between welcome string and profile icon and then use justify property to align the items to right end.

```
           <Grid container justify="flex-end">
              <Grid item>
                <Typography variant="title">Welcome User!</Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <IconButton color="inherit">
                  <Notify />
                </IconButton>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <IconButton>
                  <Avatar src="./Images/profile_image.png" />
                </IconButton>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: This answer is out of date. `justify` should be `justifyContent`.